# How to keep track of page refreshes using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I need help keeping track of a webpage refreshes for all users. I understand I need the code I wrote below but I need to store it in a MySQL database in a table called "pagecounter" that contains two columns "id" and "count". Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$query = "UPDATE pagecounter
          SET count = 1
          WHERE id = 1";

session_start();
$_SESSION['count'] = 0;
$output =  "";

if ( isset( $_SESSION['count'] ) ) 
{
    echo "{$_SESSION['count']}\n";
$_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
}
else {

    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}

?>
```

Comment: It seems you already know what to do, so what is the problem?

Comment: I'm having issues with the actual query to store that data

Comment: `I'm having issues with the actual query to store that data` what do you mean?

Comment: You have issues with your `query` yet you didn't even bother showing it.

Comment: I've added the query I was working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this,

```
<?php


session_start();
$output =  "";

if ( isset( $_SESSION['count'] ) ) 
{
echo "{$_SESSION['count']}\n";
$_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
}
else {

$_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
$query = "UPDATE pagecounter
      SET count = ".$_SESSION['count']."
      WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['userid']." ";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Wait it only does it for individual users. Not for everyone.

Comment: assuming you have saved unique user id in cookie or session(if not then saved user id), change your where condition.